# Select common files in 3 different directories

Tags: fortran

I have 3 different directories, let's say:

```
path1/directory1/
path2/directory2/
path3/directory3/
```

(the paths to the directories are not the same!)
and each directories has several files (like 200 files).

What I want to do is select the files common to all three directories (that is the intersection of `directory1`,`directory2` and `directory3`).

I am using Fortran 90 with the GNU compiler.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a tag for a specific version if necessary to distinguish. There are many things you can improve even if your English is not perfect. Try to write clear and short description of your problem. Use the Formatting features like `code` which the editor offers. Use consistent spelling of Fortran. Best is to use "Fortran", than "FORTRAN" and definitely not "fortran". Do not write about how new you are and when you started, describe your problem in a short and clear way.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "select the files common to all three directories". Actually, please explain what do you mean by "select a file". Do you have some code you can show to us? Typically a question should contain some code.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the corrections, I have taken note. What I mean by "select the files to all three directories", is just to chose say for example files named "file1" and "file2" and store them in an array if both "file1" and "file2" are present in all three directories.

Comment: Have you tried to write some code? Do you have something to start? Other people are already voting to close your question as *too broad*. It is really better to have something for a start. How do you proceed when you have just one file? The selection itself might be just a small if condition.

Comment: I wouldn't even use Fortran for this. Try `ls <dir1> <dir2> <dir3> | awk '{n[$1]++} n[$1] == 3'`